# Open home page after two minutes of inactivity

Tags: java, android, native

I need a help with the following need,

When a customer exits the app and open the app again within 2-3 minutes they should
be taken to the same page they were on when they exited. If they open the app after more
than 2-3 minutes they should be directed to the homepage.

Answer (score 1):

You can save the name of the current screen and the exit time from the application, and then compare it with the current time at the entrance

Answer (score 0):

You can use shared preferences to achieve this, While exiting the app put this in that activity's onDestroy method

```
val sps = getSharedPreferences(packageName, Context.MODE_PRIVATE)
sps.edit().putLong("last_used", Date().time).apply()
```

and during opening the app, you can check if it was used in last 2 mins in your opening app activity's onCreate method

```
val lastUsed = sps.getLong("last_used", 0L)
 if((lastUsed + 120000L /** 2 mins **/) > Date().time) {
        // navigate to home page
 } else {
        // navigate to other page
 }
```